# Exponential Smoothing Excel

Tags: python, excel, statistics, time-series

I've a table of data for which I need to exclude outliers and generate an estimated monthly base rate.

The data is a format similar to the following:

```
Product, Month 1, Month 2, Month 3, Month 4
Example, 222, 104, 1110, 223, 220
```

Within Excel, I've used the analysis packs Exponential Smoothing function to determine a base rate. This works fine, but I needed to extend this to over 550 rows of products.

Python seems like a good solution here, but I'm very rusty and was hoping for a solution that I can use in a spreadsheet to share with the team.

Comment: Exponential smoothing is the easiest (and funniest) thing to code. So the main questions here are : (1) where is your data (csv files, excel multisheets, database,...); (2) what is your team (and your) favorite programming tool ?

Comment: Why don't you do it in Excel ? Please indicate the format of your current Excel (number of sheets, row/column header+format,...). Maybe a 5 product example.